# Push not working on Parse Server after Apple push certificate renewal

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I am getting below in server log after push is sent on Parser Server. Server crash and restarts after this.

Node version 17.1.0

Parse Server - 4.2.0

This has started happening after i renewed APN certificate to the server. I tried from parse dashboard and it shows push as sent.

```
{
  "result": {
    "headers": {
      "X-Parse-Push-Status-Id": "3euayowDhH"
    },
    "response": {
      "result": true
    }
  }
}
 verbose: _PushStatus 3euayowDhH: sending push to installations with %d batches
 verbose: Sending push to 25
 /app/node_modules/parse-server/lib/ParseServer.js:229
           throw err;
           ^
 Error: unsupported
     at configSecureContext (node:internal/tls/secure-context:276:15)
     at Object.createSecureContext (node:_tls_common:116:3)
     at Object.connect (node:_tls_wrap:1621:48)
     at Object.connect (node:internal/http2/core:3262:22)
     at Client.write (/app/node_modules/@parse/node-apn/lib/client.js:37:28)
     at /app/node_modules/@parse/node-apn/lib/provider.js:29:62
     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
     at Provider.send (/app/node_modules/@parse/node-apn/lib/provider.js:29:36)
     at APNS.sendThroughProvider (/app/node_modules/@parse/push-adapter/lib/APNS.js:172:27)
     at APNS.send (/app/node_modules/@parse/push-adapter/lib/APNS.js:158:28)
```

**push config in index.js**

```
push: {
        ios: {
            pfx: 'certs/ApplePush.p12',  
            passphrase: process.env.APPLE_PUSH_PASSPHRASE,
            topic: process.env.APPLE_PUSH_TOPIC, 
            production: false 
        }
    }
```

i have moved to M1 Macbook Pro Monterey. Could that impact?

Found [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40672) issue but not sure whether related. Didn't try the command mentioned in it as i am not conversant with it.

Comment: Would you mind to share your parse server config on how you are setting the certificate?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo Do you have any suggestion? I created new certificate, set production to true but no success.

Comment: We got this same error message when we tried upgrading from Node 16 to Node 18. The fix was to generate new .p12 files for APS using a newer cryptographic algorithm: https://community.parseplatform.org/t/error-upgrading-node-16-18-unsupported-at-configsecurecontext/3706/3

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. I had overlooked that Parse Server support Node.js upto v16 an i had set my dependency to >9.0.0 so heroku was installing v17.

the URL i had posted above https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40672 should have made me  probe more.